# Windows Live ID authentication API, retired?

Tags: windows, live

I want to implement Windows Live ID authentication to use as a method to register users, like I'm doing with Facebook's Open Graph API and Google's OAuth 2.0 API. But I'm finding deprecation notices in most sites from Windows Live, it's a total mess.

So, if I create my app here https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index, will this service be disabled next week or next month?

If you search for "**Windows Live Authentication API**", the first result is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx, where you can read:

> This topic describes functionality that will be obsolete. This
>   functionality is provided only to support legacy applications. Live
>   Connect incorporates features that provide equivalent functionality.

Now, the **"Live Connect"** (?) link takes me to the **"Live SDK"** download page (??), which also redirects me to the **"OneDrive Dev Center"** (¿¿??!), which has nothing to do with the authentication API. I'm completely lost now.

I assume they are about the get rid of the Authentication API completely, and I'll be wasting time dealing with that API which will be retired in a matter of minutes probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the service you want is being discontinued in July as far as I have found. In particular the very popular free service at http://domains.live.com which supported authentication for private domains is being replaced with Office 360 based equivalent, where the charge is $60 per user per year. Not very friendly to small business or community services that used this authentication to offer very secure authentication to the subscribers to their websites.